# Can a non-Jew visit a Jewish cemetery to see how it looks?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, cemetery-grave

I want to know whether a non-Jew can, according to Jewish law, enter and visit a Jewish cemetery, to know what it looks like and what symbols and images are used in the cemetery, for personal knowledge.

Comment: Kam, the following is a reference to symbols used in Jewish Cemetaries:  http://www.jewishgen.org/infofiles/tombstones.html  The only "restriction" you may experience visiting a Jewish cemetery is closure due to the Sabbath and Jewish holy days. In terms of service, Orthodox Judaism does have a liturgy for funerals. A Judaica store should be able to recommend to you a book on death and bereavement.

Comment: As an aside, even for Jews (if there is a difference in this case, not sure if there is), it's not recommended to look at gravestones. There are mystical reasons that say it's not recommended, and the Mishnah Berurah (I believe) brings it down as well.

Answer (score 3):

Non-Jews can come to the service at the cemetery to honor the person.  So I would presume they can come be in the cemetery as long as they ask at the front for any respectful instructions (such as walkable areas.)  Non-Jews as well as Jews visit the famous graves of patriarchs and matriarchs in Israel.  Hope that helps.