# Is it appropriate for a Jew to visit a grave of a non-Jewish friend who passed away?

Tags: cemetery-grave

I learned that an old friend who I have been out of touch with for 15 years passed away a couple years ago, at a very young age. They were not Jewish. I am wondering if it is appropriate to visit their gravesite and if doing so carries the same significance as a Jewish grave. (i.e. that the neshama hovers over the gravesite, etc.)

I am looking for some Jewish perspective as to the best way to make peace with the news that I heard. I am feeling bad for having been out of touch all these years and thinking of all of the things that I would say to them today if they were still alive. I guess am wondering if it would be appropriate to go to their gravesite and say those things.

Are there sources that suggest the notion of the dead being "aware" of what we say at their gravesite applies to non-Jews as well as Jews (or any reason to think otherwise)?

I intend to check with a local rabbi if I have any questions on specifics, but I would appreciate any information anyone here has to share on the topic. Thank you.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62016/can-a-non-jew-visit-a-jewish-cemetery-to-see-how-it-looks and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59633/is-an-jew-allowed-to-visit-a-christian-cemetery

Comment: As an aside, where they are buried can have a significant impact to the practicalities here.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Please explain. I'm unaware of a prohibition of a Jew visiting a non-Jewish cemetery.

Comment: @DanF If they're buried in a church yard things could become problematic.

Comment: @ezra such as..

Comment: @DanF if it looks like you are going to church, could be an issue. If there are lots of crosses, and you'll be bending over could be an issue etc.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Per Baba Metziah 114, there is no problem visiting a Gentile cemetery. Your items pose a separate issue. There is a debate regarding a Jew attending a church. Here, you're not attending the church, so if you think it's a *Marit Ayin* issue it would be so only on something that's definitely forbidden. Bowing to a cross, seems problematic. Overall, it seems that you have enough elements to compose an answer.

Comment: Why would you not show love by visiting the graved of a loved one, no matter what their religion/race/creed/etc? Your heart is still hurting.

Comment: @Gary Halacha doesn't always cater to our emotional needs.

Comment: @ezra - well if some parts of it say to do things for Gentiles "for the sake of maintaining peace"(despite emotions), how much more so for someone you loved like a brother/sister?

Comment: @Gary A Kohen isn't allowed to go even to his own parents' grave (after the funeral), no matter how much his heart is hurting. There is room for emotion in Halachah, but even the emotion has to follow the correct guidelines (there are also distinct guidelines on how to apply "for the sake of maintaining peace" as well).

Comment: @Salmononius2 - right!  But the question isn't asking about halacha for Kohens specifically, just a "Jewish perspective".  hopefully there'll be a good answer to this one posted, it's a good question.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. And I appreciate what you have to say @Gary as well as the other points where we ultimately follow the Torah and trust that it will be OK . If there is a halachic issue of actually being there (due to crosses, for example), I will seek guidance from a local Orthodox rabbi.

I am really more interested in the whole idea of "talking" to somebody at their gravesite. And if such a practice would be any different for a non-Jew. Do we have any sources that talk about that?

Thanks!